# Does anyone knows how to complete my figure. It somehow not showing the last 3 data. What went wrong?

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure, subplot

[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpMP2.png)

And here is my code :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('joox.csv', index_col=0, encoding='latin-1')
df= pd.DataFrame(data, columns= data.columns)
corr = data.corr()
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
cax = ax.matshow(corr,cmap='coolwarm', vmin=-1, vmax=1)
fig.colorbar(cax)
ticks = np.arange(0,len(data.columns),1)
ax.set_xticks(ticks)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
ax.set_yticks(ticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(data.columns)
ax.set_yticklabels(data.columns)
plt.show()
```

I don't what is the cause of the last 3 of my columns data not showing up in the figure ( not showing any color ), please help, thanks in advance

Comment: Please add a link to your csv file in the question for recreating the issue

Comment: check your Acousticness, speechiness, popularity they are non numerical right?

Comment: "pd.DataFrame.corr simply ignores non-numerical (i.e., non-float or non-integer values) and drops these columns"

Comment: @Pygirl THANK YOUU SO MUCHH, but is it possible to correlate with a non-float data?

Comment: Do you mean categorical data?

Comment: yes, my example was the music genre @Pygirl

Comment: between categorical and float @Pygirl

Comment: This might help you: https://medium.com/@outside2SDs/an-overview-of-correlation-measures-between-categorical-and-continuous-variables-4c7f85610365
See the summary at the end.